How to change billboard.js chart type after generation?
I'm trying to change the chart type on the fly (ie from a dropdown), just like we have in C3's .transform API, but couldn't find any easy way to do it.
It works when I call chart.load() with same data and a similar type (eg bar <-> line and pie <-> donut) but does NOT work with different types (eg bar <-> pie).

Took me a long time to find this info, so I decided to post this for others that might face the same challenge.

Explanation
Turns out that this API has been removed on v2 in favor of reduced code complexity.

At the initialization, even though isn't necessary to be generated,
some elements are generated.

Ex. if generate 'pie' type, axis elements are generated also.

The primary reason of this behavior comes from the possibility of the
transforming type generated to different one. With this assumption,
makes harder to optimize and complicating the process in general.

Reference issue naver/billboard.js#801.

Solution
Regenerate the chart using the same data, but using the new type:


changeType('pie');

function changeType(chartType) {
  bb.generate({ // re-generate the chart
    data: {
      columns: [
        ["data1", 30],
        ["data2", 130],
        ["data3", 15],
      ],
      type: chartType, // with new type
    },
    bindto: "#chart"
  });
}
<script src="https://naver.github.io/billboard.js/release/latest/dist/billboard.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://naver.github.io/billboard.js/release/latest/dist/theme/datalab.min.css" />

Click the button to change type: 
<button onclick="changeType('bar')">Change to bar chart</button>
<div id="chart"></div>



